# How to interact with window element (for file upload) from Jenkins with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation

I am using Java and Selenium to automate my tests.
One of my tests needs to upload an image from the computer.
I used Robot object to recognize the upload window and set the path of the file.
When running the test via IntelliJ everything is OK, as the browser comes to front, including the upload window.
When I run the test through Jenkins, the browser and the upload window remain at the back and fail to upload the file.

I tried several ways to bring the windows to the front and they all work only when running directly via IntelliJ, but it's still a problem with Jenkins.

driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
or
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");

Any idea how to handle this uploading window?

```
public static void uploadFile(String filePath) throws AWTException
    {
        //Copy the file path to the clipboard
        SystemOps.setClipboardData(filePath);

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        sleepUninterruptibly(3000);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ku8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what I have done to solve it:

I installed AutoIt FULL INSTALLATION from their website:
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

Then installed AutoIt editor (same page) but redirects here:
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/

In the past they had a recorder that enabled recording AutoIt scripts, but no more.
In order to download the recorder you can download the zip from here:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip
Extract it, and copy the 'Au3Record' folder under 'Extras' folder and put it in the existing 'Extras' folder you already have.
This recorder exe file enables you to record steps you do on window-based apps and convert them to scripts.

My approach was to create a function that would copy the file path and paste it to the upload window, rather then type it, as I didn't want / know how to modify the exe file every time, and it works for me this way.

Open a text file and paste this code:

```
_WinWaitActivate("Open","")
Send("{ALTDOWN}n{ALTUP}{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
MouseClick("left",514,441,1)
```

(The Alt+N is just to make sure we are focusing on the file input field)

Save the file as uploadFile.au3 somewhere in your project.

Convert the file to an .exe file:

Open 'Aut2exe' under Aut2exe folder. Convert the .au3 file you created to .exe
Place the file in your project.

The code:

```
public static void uploadFile(String filePath) throws IOException
{

//Copy the file path to the clipboard
SystemOps.setClipboardData(filePath);

    //Execute the exe + Location of folder 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./AutoItExeFiles/uploadFile.exe");

    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

 /**
 * Sets any parameter string to the system's clipboard.
 * @param string the string to copy to the clipboard
 */
public static void setClipboardData(String string)
{
    //StringSelection is a class that can be used for copy and paste operations.
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```